# I'm out of my mind - I'm out of mind - Are both correct?

Tags: difference, phrase-usage

Is it correct to say "I'm out of mind" or does it have to be "I'm out of **my** mind"?

Online translators like Google Translate or DeepL say that both work and both have the same meaning (I'm crazy).

I make music as a hobby and I used the line "I'm out of mind" in one of my songs. I was just wondering if it's correct.

Comment: You don't have to write "thank you" in your question or in a comment, much less in the answer box. Upvoting is the way to express gratitude on this site. The answer box should only be used for answers.

Answer (score 4):

They are both idioms, and, generally speaking, they mean completely different things.

---

### Out of my mind

[**out of one's mind**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/out%20of%20one%27s%20mind)

> [Merriam-Webster]
> : not sane : crazy
> // What a ridiculous idea! You must be *out of your mind* to believe that.

This is often used more figuratively than literally. People are often said to be out of their minds with grief or worry.

---

### Out of mind

[**out of sight, out of mind**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/out%20of%20sight,%20out%20of%20mind)

> [Merriam-Webster]
> —used to mean that a person stops thinking about something or someone if he or she does not see that thing or person for a period of time

Saying just *I'm out of mind* would be unusual, but it would mean that you're not in the thoughts of anybody.

---

Which one to use in a song would depend on the meaning being conveyed.

Answer (score 0):

Out of mind: Forgotten about or ignored, not important.

Out of my mind: A state of confusion where all your faculties are taken by a single thought process

Comment: A little more explanation would be helpful in showing the OP which they should use.

Answer (score 0):

Do not rely on online translators. They are very bad language guides. To use 'out of' and 'mind' to say that someone is insane or 'crazy', you need a possessive pronoun such as my, your, his, her, etc. I am out of **my** mind, she is out of **he**r mind, etc. 'Out of mind' is an old fashioned phrase meaning 'forgotten, overlooked, insignificant, not readily remembered'.

Comment: online translation programs, not translators which are people.